# Entity Framework Self referencing 1 to 1 optional relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

So I have a table called **Contact** and it can be of different types. And I want the table to be able to have a One-One, One-Many or One-Zero/One relationship with itself. Is that possible? And if so, how?

For instance, a Contact can have a Spouse, which is just another Contact in the database. The Contact can also be of type Organization, in which case the the Contact can have a One-to-Many relationship with other Contacts.

This is what I'm doing in the domain class.

```
public class Contact
{
  public Contact()
  {
    public int ContactId {get; set;}
    ...
    public int SpouseId {get; set;}
    public virtual Contact Spouse {get; set;}
    public in OrgId {get; set;}
    public virtual Contact Organization {get; set;}

    private ICollection<Contact> _individuals;
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Individuals
    {
      get {return _individuals;}
      set {_individuals = value; }
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

I need to know how to map this properly in the OnModelCreating() in the Context. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Totally possible but you'll have to represent one-to-one relationships as a single-element collection.

Answer (score 1):

Something smells fishy here.  If an organization is a contact and contact has a spouse then an organization has a spouse?

I think you need a contactBase class:

```
public class Contact {
   int ContactId
   ICollection<Contact> Contacts
   EntityTypeEnum EntityType
}
```

But on second thought you might want to switch to a graph database, because it sounds like your describing nodes and relationships.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well the Spouse is a 1-0..1 relationship. As is the Organization. Is the contactBase class supposed to be a parent class? And all Contact/Org/Spouse inherit from it?

Comment: Yes. You would have a Person:ContactBase and an Organization:ComtactBase. That way u could have spouse as a property of person but not of organization. (Spouse would just be another instance of person).